# Using organization in biblatex authortitle style

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with the `authortitle`-style and showing the references in footnotes using `\autocite`.

I use `@manual` for some of my bib-entries because they don't have an author or don't specify one.

How can I change the content of the footnote to show the author if available and fall back to the organization otherwise?

Comment: You can also specify an organisation in the `author` field; of course, you should only do that if the organisation really is the author of that particular `@manual`. See also §2.3.3 *Corporate Authors and Editors*, p. 30, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "organization" is indeed the author of the work, there is no harm in specifying the organization as `author`.

`biblatex` allows for §2.3.3 *Corporate Authors and Editors*, see the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

You could go with

```
author      = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
shortauthor = {NASA},
```

for example.